# Keep Textinputlayout hint always top

Tags: android, android-edittext, textinputlayout

Would be possible have my hint text always top, as if it were focusable?

I tried this:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/etSurnameInput"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/llNameImage"
            android:hint="My Hint Text"
            app:hintEnabled="true"
            app:hintAnimationEnabled="false"
            android:textColorHint="@color/gray_title">
```

Comment: you want it for all your fields?

Comment: what is the current behavior because this `app:hintAnimationEnabled="false"` should work ?

Comment: @RushiAyyappa yes, i want to all my fields

Comment: In that case use TextView.. Text input layout will animate up only if there is a focus on that field.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Actually, from `com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha03` or higher, you can simply set `app:expandedHintEnabled="false"` to make it always float.

Comment: great updated answer! thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Here's a hack - programmatically add a space in the text if it's empty. However, you would then have to remove the space if it's focused, else the user will start typing with a leading whitespace. Another option is to always `trim` the text typed by user.

Answer (score 3):

My final solution back then was to actually just set hintEnabled="false" & use a TextView on top.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `android:minLines="2"` to the `TextInputEditText` or greater than 2. Also keep `android:gravity="top"`

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:minLines="2" />
```

Answer (score 0):

set android:textAlignment="center" to TextInputEditText and android:gravity="start" to TextInputLayout

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/tilName"
                app:expandedHintEnabled="false"
                android:hint="@string/name_hint"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:hint="@string/name_hint"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:id="@+id/fieldName"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />
```