# Set hint on top of TextInputEditText in TextInputLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

How to set hint of `TextInputEditText` on top of view.

I have the following edit text that user will type description of the product, but hint is on center of view.
[image]

Here is the `XML` code.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/interestDescriptionView"
    style="@style/TextInputLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:maxLines="5"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tagsView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/titleView"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/interestDescriptionEditTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:hint="Descrição *"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="start|top"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
        android:importantForAutofill="no" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40866229/keep-textinputlayout-hint-always-top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `android:minLines` to 2 or greater .. this will make it work

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/interestDescriptionView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:hint="Descrição *"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textview"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/interestDescriptionEditTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
        android:maxLines="5"
        android:minLines="2"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Also you can check other workarounds from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40866229/keep-textinputlayout-hint-always-top)

[image]